How can I define the area where I move my finger with SwiftUI?
When I move my finger over a picture with SwiftUI, I want to scan the area I move, I want it to be hollow and have edges, I have tried many ways to do it with path or canvas, lots of draggesture views, but I could not add a border to the edges and I could not do it by giving a diameter, I can only draw a line, how can I do this, I am attaching a sample image.
I move my finger over the image and when I release it, I want the area I pass to appear as follows, I tried algorithms such as convex hull and I could not find a solution.
Here what I tried.
struct Circular: View {
    @State private var erasedPoints: [CGPoint] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("img4")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .overlay(
                    Color.red
                        .mask(eraserShape())
                        .blendMode(.colorDodge)
                )
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .onChanged { value in
                            erasedPoints.append(value.location)
                        }
                )
        }
    }
    
    func eraserShape() -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        for point in erasedPoints {
            let rect = CGRect(x: point.x - 15, y: point.y - 15, width: 30, height: 30)
            path.addEllipse(in: rect)
        }
        return path
    }
}


My result.

what I want to achieve


We can’t help you troubleshoot if you don’t share what you have and tell us what isn’t working.

updated, basically what I did.

Instead of adding ellipses to the path, you should draw a line connecting on the erasedPoints.
Then get the shape that would be formed if this line is to be stroked using a 30pt line width, using strokedPath.
Stroking this shape gives you the desired result. But before that, you should also normalized(eoFill: false), because apparently the path produced by strokedPath is a bit messy.
func eraserShape() -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    path.addLines(erasedPoints)
    return path
        .strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 30, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        .normalized(eoFill: false)
}

and change the overlay of the image to:
.overlay {
    eraserShape().stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 3)
}


For iOS 16, you can work directly with the CGPath instead:
func eraserShape() -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    path.addLines(erasedPoints)
    return Path(
        path.cgPath
            .copy(strokingWithWidth: 30, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 10)
            .normalized(using: .winding)
    )
}


Thanks! its working but need a little update.
func eraserShape() -> Path {
var path = Path()
path.addLines(erasedPoints)
return path
.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 30, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
.normalized(eoFill: false)
}
it was also drawing random straight lines, if we make the lineJoin parameter .round, we will solve this too. thank you again.

@dshn Really? I know it draws randomly straight lines without normalized, but in my testing that didn't come up. Anyway I've updated the answer.

done!
so, an another question I have.
How can I use this drawn area as a clipShape? I want to cut any view with clipShape as I have drawn.

@dshn Just pass eraserShape() directly to clipShape, without stroking.

im so sorry but I need that in iOS 15, .normalized in iOS 17...

@dshn Unfortunately CGPath.normalized is available since iOS 16. I don't know how to do this on iOS 15, sorry.
